# psql connection with postgres uri and special character

Tags: postgresql, docker, passwords, psql

I was messing around with postgres in docker and wanted to connect to it via url URI.

If the password contains a substring that could be transformed as a character thanks to `decodeURIComponent`, it will be treated as well, leading to a connection fail.

Is it possible to specify some character in the uri that should not be considered as special characters to decode?

Here is an example:

`%23` is automatically encoded as `#`

```sh
$> docker run --name test -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret%23 --rm -d postgres
$> psql postgres://user:secret%23@localhost:5433/db
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
$> PGPASSWORD=secret%23 psql --user=user --host=localhost --port=5433 --dbname=db
psql (12.3, server 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.
db=#
```

Working example (without a percent followed by two digits):

```sh
$> docker run --name test2 -p 5434:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret# --rm -d postgres
$> psql postgres://user:secret%23@localhost:5434/db
psql (12.3, server 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.
db=# 
$> PGPASSWORD=secret# psql --user=user --host=localhost --port=5434 --dbname=db
psql (12.3, server 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1))
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 13.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.
db=#
```

`psql postgres://user:secret%23@localhost:5433/db` does not work with a password set to `secret%23` but does with one set to `secret#`.

Is it possible to use database uri with a password like `secret%23`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) says the connection URI must be encoded, so your value of `%23` must be encoded to `%2523`.

Comment: I did not even realize I should encode `%` hahaha